# Regularity of Special Measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

(1) Show that the counting measure on $\Bbb Z$ with the induced metric
from $\Bbb R$ is regular. (2) Show that the delta measure with respect to
a point $x_0$ on any metric space is regular.

What I know is: A measure $\mu$ on a metric space with a given $\sigma$-algebra $M$
  is called regular, if the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets is a
  subalgebra of $M$, and for every set $A$ in $M$, we have
$\mu (A) = \inf \{ \mu (U) \; | \; U \text{ is open and } A \subset U \}$
and $\mu (A) = \sup \{ \mu (K) \; | \; K \text{ is compact and } K \subset A \}$.

Please give hints on both the parts on how to proceed.

Comment: 1) Hmm so the topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ is just the discrete topology (i.e. any set of integers is open). Then the Borel sets are just all subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$, and of course these are measurable with counting measure. So then you do some definition checking with the $\sup$ and $\inf$.

2) For the case of a delta measure at $x_0$, every subset of the metric space is measurable, so then the Borel sets are definitely measurable. Then more definition checking... :)

Is that enough?

Comment: @dalbrit: Any hints on counting measure with inf and sup?

Comment: Sure! To check that $\mu(A)$ is the $\inf$ you wrote above, we want the inequalities $\inf \leq \mu(A) \leq \inf$. Now, the inequality $\mu(A) \leq \inf$ follows from the fact that any open $B$ containing $A$ satisfies $\mu(A) \leq \mu(B)$, just from the properties of measure (or properties of counting things). To get the other inequality, use the fact that all sets are open in this topology (even $A$ itself). As for the $\sup$, you can use the same strategy, but you might have to make an extra case when $\mu(A)=\infty$. Recall that compact sets are just the finite sets, in this topology.